# fit elements inside their container when decreasing the height of the container

Tags: html, css

I have a row of SVG boxes with a background of a rectangle also in SVG. (I need them to be like this)

Here is the code when `.main-container`'s width is `width: 300px;`

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Heebo-Light";
  src: url(Heebo-Light.ttf) format("truetype");
}

svg {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: visible;
    pointer-events: none;
}


body {
  background-color: #FDFDFD;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box svg:nth-of-type(1) {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
 
}

.box svg:nth-of-type(2) {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;

}

.subbox-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 3px;

   
}

.main-container {

  width: 300px; 
  gap: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px dashed;

}

.background-rectangle {
  transform: translate(3.21vw, -3.18vh); 
}

.box-container {
  position: relative;
  transform: translate(-3.21vw);
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;


}


.box, .background-rectangle, svg {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
</head>

<body> 

<div class="main-container">


    <!-- box-container start -->

    <div id="box-container-1" class="box-container">

    <div class="subbox-container">

        <!-- Start Box -->
        <div class ="box" style="min-width: 0; min-height: 0; margin: 0; z-index: 4; width: 15.54vw; height: 5.59vh; opacity: 1; transform-origin: 8.39vw 2.79vh; transform: translate(3.21vw, 11vh) rotate(0deg) scale(1, 1);" aria-label="do you ever">

            <svg height="5.59vh" width="15.54vw" viewBox="0 0 172 45">
                <text font-family="Heebo-Light" font-size="24px" fill="#595959" fill-opacity="1" x="50%" y="53%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">
                  <tspan>do you ever</tspan>
               </text> 
            </svg>

            <svg height="5.59vh" width="15.54vw" viewBox="0 0 272 45" preserveAspectRatio="none">

                <defs>

                   <linearGradient gradientTransform="rotate(90, 0.5, 0.5)" id="uniqueDomId-1114">
                      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#AFAFAF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#F5F3F8" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                      <stop offset="69.804%" stop-color="#F9F9F9" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                   </linearGradient>

                   <filter id="uniqueDomId-1115" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-15.75" y="-15.75" width="303.5" height="76.5">
                      <feFlood result="floodOut" flood-color="#CCC1DA" flood-opacity="0.29"></feFlood>
                      <feGaussianBlur result="gaussOut" in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2.450000047683716,2.450000047683716">
                      </feGaussianBlur>
                      <feComposite in="floodOut" in2="gaussOut" operator="in"></feComposite>
                   </filter>

                </defs>

                <use transform="translate(-2.72, -0.45) scale(1.0199999809265137, 1.0199999809265137) translate(0, 0)" xlink:href="#uniqueDomId-1116" filter="url(#uniqueDomId-1115)" data-angle="0" data-distance="0" data-height="45" data-scale="1.02" data-adornment-type="drop-shadow" data-width="272" data-transform="[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;translate&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[-2.72,-0.45]},{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;scale&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[1.0199999809265137,1.0199999809265137]}]"></use>

                <g id="uniqueDomId-1116">
                   <g id="uniqueDomId-1117">
                      <path d="M0,0L272,0 272,45 0,45z" id="uniqueDomId-1118" fill="url(#uniqueDomId-1114)"></path>
                   </g>
                   
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <!-- End Box -->


        <!-- Start Box -->
        <div class ="box" style="min-width: 0; min-height: 0; margin: 0; z-index: 4; width: 15.54vw; height: 5.59vh; opacity: 1; transform-origin: 8.39vw 2.79vh; transform: translate(3.21vw, 11vh) rotate(0deg) scale(1, 1);" aria-label="do you ever">

            <svg height="5.59vh" width="15.54vw" viewBox="0 0 172 45">
                <text font-family="Heebo-Light" font-size="24px" fill="#595959" fill-opacity="1" x="50%" y="53%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">
                  <tspan>do you ever</tspan>
               </text> 
            </svg>

            <svg height="5.59vh" width="15.54vw" viewBox="0 0 272 45" preserveAspectRatio="none">

                <defs>

                   <linearGradient gradientTransform="rotate(90, 0.5, 0.5)" id="uniqueDomId-1114">
                      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#AFAFAF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#F5F3F8" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                      <stop offset="69.804%" stop-color="#F9F9F9" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                   </linearGradient>

                   <filter id="uniqueDomId-1115" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-15.75" y="-15.75" width="303.5" height="76.5">
                      <feFlood result="floodOut" flood-color="#CCC1DA" flood-opacity="0.29"></feFlood>
                      <feGaussianBlur result="gaussOut" in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2.450000047683716,2.450000047683716">
                      </feGaussianBlur>
                      <feComposite in="floodOut" in2="gaussOut" operator="in"></feComposite>
                   </filter>

                </defs>

                <use transform="translate(-2.72, -0.45) scale(1.0199999809265137, 1.0199999809265137) translate(0, 0)" xlink:href="#uniqueDomId-1116" filter="url(#uniqueDomId-1115)" data-angle="0" data-distance="0" data-height="45" data-scale="1.02" data-adornment-type="drop-shadow" data-width="272" data-transform="[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;translate&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[-2.72,-0.45]},{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;scale&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[1.0199999809265137,1.0199999809265137]}]"></use>

                <g id="uniqueDomId-1116">
                   <g id="uniqueDomId-1117">
                      <path d="M0,0L272,0 272,45 0,45z" id="uniqueDomId-1118" fill="url(#uniqueDomId-1114)"></path>
                   </g>
                   
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <!-- End Box -->

    </div>

    <!-- background rectangle -->
    <div class="background-rectangle" style="min-width: 0; min-height: 0; height: 16.81vh; width: 15.54vw;">
        <svg height="16.81vh" width="15.54vw" viewBox="0 0 272 186" data-commandset-id="35" preserveAspectRatio="none">
            <g >
                <path d="M259.147003,1E-06C266.245483,-1.2E-05 271.999939,5.754436 271.999969,12.852937 271.999969,12.85294 271.999969,12.852942 271.999969,12.852945L271.999969,12.852945L271.999969,171.147034C271.999969,178.245529 266.245514,183.999985 259.147034,183.999985L259.147034,183.999985L12.852946,183.999985C5.754463,183.999985 3E-06,178.245529 0,171.147049L0,171.147049L0,12.85295C-5E-06,5.754468 5.754446,7E-06 12.852927,-1E-06z" id="uniqueDomId-1466" fill="#E6E0EC" fill-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="1" stroke="#CCC1DA" stroke-opacity="0.14" stroke-linecap="flat" stroke-linejoin="round" data-stroke-sharpened="true" transform="translate(0.5, 0.5)"></path>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>

    </div>

    <!-- box-container end -->


</div> <!-- main container end-->


<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

So far when you decrease the `width` of the `.main-container` to something like `50px` all the elements get fit to the new container's width. and this is acceptable behavior.

So the result with `.main-container` with `width: 50px;`

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Heebo-Light";
  src: url(Heebo-Light.ttf) format("truetype");
}

svg {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: visible;
    pointer-events: none;
}


body {
  background-color: #FDFDFD;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box svg:nth-of-type(1) {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
 
}

.box svg:nth-of-type(2) {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;

}

.subbox-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 3px;

   
}

.main-container {

  width: 50px;  
  gap: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px dashed;

}

.background-rectangle {
  transform: translate(3.21vw, -3.18vh); 
}

.box-container {
  position: relative;
  transform: translate(-3.21vw);
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;


}


.box, .background-rectangle, svg {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
</head>

<body> 

<div class="main-container">


    <!-- box-container start -->

    <div id="box-container-1" class="box-container">

    <div class="subbox-container">

        <!-- Start Box -->
        <div class ="box" style="min-width: 0; min-height: 0; margin: 0; z-index: 4; width: 15.54vw; height: 5.59vh; opacity: 1; transform-origin: 8.39vw 2.79vh; transform: translate(3.21vw, 11vh) rotate(0deg) scale(1, 1);" aria-label="do you ever">

            <svg height="5.59vh" width="15.54vw" viewBox="0 0 172 45">
                <text font-family="Heebo-Light" font-size="24px" fill="#595959" fill-opacity="1" x="50%" y="53%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">
                  <tspan>do you ever</tspan>
               </text> 
            </svg>

            <svg height="5.59vh" width="15.54vw" viewBox="0 0 272 45" preserveAspectRatio="none">

                <defs>

                   <linearGradient gradientTransform="rotate(90, 0.5, 0.5)" id="uniqueDomId-1114">
                      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#AFAFAF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#F5F3F8" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                      <stop offset="69.804%" stop-color="#F9F9F9" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                   </linearGradient>

                   <filter id="uniqueDomId-1115" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-15.75" y="-15.75" width="303.5" height="76.5">
                      <feFlood result="floodOut" flood-color="#CCC1DA" flood-opacity="0.29"></feFlood>
                      <feGaussianBlur result="gaussOut" in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2.450000047683716,2.450000047683716">
                      </feGaussianBlur>
                      <feComposite in="floodOut" in2="gaussOut" operator="in"></feComposite>
                   </filter>

                </defs>

                <use transform="translate(-2.72, -0.45) scale(1.0199999809265137, 1.0199999809265137) translate(0, 0)" xlink:href="#uniqueDomId-1116" filter="url(#uniqueDomId-1115)" data-angle="0" data-distance="0" data-height="45" data-scale="1.02" data-adornment-type="drop-shadow" data-width="272" data-transform="[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;translate&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[-2.72,-0.45]},{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;scale&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[1.0199999809265137,1.0199999809265137]}]"></use>

                <g id="uniqueDomId-1116">
                   <g id="uniqueDomId-1117">
                      <path d="M0,0L272,0 272,45 0,45z" id="uniqueDomId-1118" fill="url(#uniqueDomId-1114)"></path>
                   </g>
                   
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <!-- End Box -->


        <!-- Start Box -->
        <div class ="box" style="min-width: 0; min-height: 0; margin: 0; z-index: 4; width: 15.54vw; height: 5.59vh; opacity: 1; transform-origin: 8.39vw 2.79vh; transform: translate(3.21vw, 11vh) rotate(0deg) scale(1, 1);" aria-label="do you ever">

            <svg height="5.59vh" width="15.54vw" viewBox="0 0 172 45">
                <text font-family="Heebo-Light" font-size="24px" fill="#595959" fill-opacity="1" x="50%" y="53%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">
                  <tspan>do you ever</tspan>
               </text> 
            </svg>

            <svg height="5.59vh" width="15.54vw" viewBox="0 0 272 45" preserveAspectRatio="none">

                <defs>

                   <linearGradient gradientTransform="rotate(90, 0.5, 0.5)" id="uniqueDomId-1114">
                      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#AFAFAF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#F5F3F8" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                      <stop offset="69.804%" stop-color="#F9F9F9" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                   </linearGradient>

                   <filter id="uniqueDomId-1115" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-15.75" y="-15.75" width="303.5" height="76.5">
                      <feFlood result="floodOut" flood-color="#CCC1DA" flood-opacity="0.29"></feFlood>
                      <feGaussianBlur result="gaussOut" in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2.450000047683716,2.450000047683716">
                      </feGaussianBlur>
                      <feComposite in="floodOut" in2="gaussOut" operator="in"></feComposite>
                   </filter>

                </defs>

                <use transform="translate(-2.72, -0.45) scale(1.0199999809265137, 1.0199999809265137) translate(0, 0)" xlink:href="#uniqueDomId-1116" filter="url(#uniqueDomId-1115)" data-angle="0" data-distance="0" data-height="45" data-scale="1.02" data-adornment-type="drop-shadow" data-width="272" data-transform="[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;translate&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[-2.72,-0.45]},{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;scale&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[1.0199999809265137,1.0199999809265137]}]"></use>

                <g id="uniqueDomId-1116">
                   <g id="uniqueDomId-1117">
                      <path d="M0,0L272,0 272,45 0,45z" id="uniqueDomId-1118" fill="url(#uniqueDomId-1114)"></path>
                   </g>
                   
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <!-- End Box -->

    </div>

    <!-- background rectangle -->
    <div class="background-rectangle" style="min-width: 0; min-height: 0; height: 16.81vh; width: 15.54vw;">
        <svg height="16.81vh" width="15.54vw" viewBox="0 0 272 186" data-commandset-id="35" preserveAspectRatio="none">
            <g >
                <path d="M259.147003,1E-06C266.245483,-1.2E-05 271.999939,5.754436 271.999969,12.852937 271.999969,12.85294 271.999969,12.852942 271.999969,12.852945L271.999969,12.852945L271.999969,171.147034C271.999969,178.245529 266.245514,183.999985 259.147034,183.999985L259.147034,183.999985L12.852946,183.999985C5.754463,183.999985 3E-06,178.245529 0,171.147049L0,171.147049L0,12.85295C-5E-06,5.754468 5.754446,7E-06 12.852927,-1E-06z" id="uniqueDomId-1466" fill="#E6E0EC" fill-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="1" stroke="#CCC1DA" stroke-opacity="0.14" stroke-linecap="flat" stroke-linejoin="round" data-stroke-sharpened="true" transform="translate(0.5, 0.5)"></path>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>

    </div>

    <!-- box-container end -->


</div> <!-- main container end-->


<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The issue is I want to fit the row inside the container even if you decrease the height of the container. now the whole thing overflowing the container when there is not enough height.

So if we set the height of `.main-container` to `height: 20px;`

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Heebo-Light";
  src: url(Heebo-Light.ttf) format("truetype");
}

svg {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: visible;
    pointer-events: none;
}


body {
  background-color: #FDFDFD;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box svg:nth-of-type(1) {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
 
}

.box svg:nth-of-type(2) {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;

}

.subbox-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 3px;

   
}

.main-container {
  
  height: 20px;
  /*width: 300px;*/ 
  gap: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px dashed;

}

.background-rectangle {
  transform: translate(3.21vw, -3.18vh); 
}

.box-container {
  position: relative;
  transform: translate(-3.21vw);
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;


}


.box, .background-rectangle, svg {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
</head>

<body> 

<div class="main-container">


    <!-- box-container start -->

    <div id="box-container-1" class="box-container">

    <div class="subbox-container">

        <!-- Start Box -->
        <div class ="box" style="min-width: 0; min-height: 0; margin: 0; z-index: 4; width: 15.54vw; height: 5.59vh; opacity: 1; transform-origin: 8.39vw 2.79vh; transform: translate(3.21vw, 11vh) rotate(0deg) scale(1, 1);" aria-label="do you ever">

            <svg height="5.59vh" width="15.54vw" viewBox="0 0 172 45">
                <text font-family="Heebo-Light" font-size="24px" fill="#595959" fill-opacity="1" x="50%" y="53%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">
                  <tspan>do you ever</tspan>
               </text> 
            </svg>

            <svg height="5.59vh" width="15.54vw" viewBox="0 0 272 45" preserveAspectRatio="none">

                <defs>

                   <linearGradient gradientTransform="rotate(90, 0.5, 0.5)" id="uniqueDomId-1114">
                      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#AFAFAF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#F5F3F8" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                      <stop offset="69.804%" stop-color="#F9F9F9" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                   </linearGradient>

                   <filter id="uniqueDomId-1115" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-15.75" y="-15.75" width="303.5" height="76.5">
                      <feFlood result="floodOut" flood-color="#CCC1DA" flood-opacity="0.29"></feFlood>
                      <feGaussianBlur result="gaussOut" in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2.450000047683716,2.450000047683716">
                      </feGaussianBlur>
                      <feComposite in="floodOut" in2="gaussOut" operator="in"></feComposite>
                   </filter>

                </defs>

                <use transform="translate(-2.72, -0.45) scale(1.0199999809265137, 1.0199999809265137) translate(0, 0)" xlink:href="#uniqueDomId-1116" filter="url(#uniqueDomId-1115)" data-angle="0" data-distance="0" data-height="45" data-scale="1.02" data-adornment-type="drop-shadow" data-width="272" data-transform="[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;translate&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[-2.72,-0.45]},{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;scale&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[1.0199999809265137,1.0199999809265137]}]"></use>

                <g id="uniqueDomId-1116">
                   <g id="uniqueDomId-1117">
                      <path d="M0,0L272,0 272,45 0,45z" id="uniqueDomId-1118" fill="url(#uniqueDomId-1114)"></path>
                   </g>
                   
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <!-- End Box -->


        <!-- Start Box -->
        <div class ="box" style="min-width: 0; min-height: 0; margin: 0; z-index: 4; width: 15.54vw; height: 5.59vh; opacity: 1; transform-origin: 8.39vw 2.79vh; transform: translate(3.21vw, 11vh) rotate(0deg) scale(1, 1);" aria-label="do you ever">

            <svg height="5.59vh" width="15.54vw" viewBox="0 0 172 45">
                <text font-family="Heebo-Light" font-size="24px" fill="#595959" fill-opacity="1" x="50%" y="53%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">
                  <tspan>do you ever</tspan>
               </text> 
            </svg>

            <svg height="5.59vh" width="15.54vw" viewBox="0 0 272 45" preserveAspectRatio="none">

                <defs>

                   <linearGradient gradientTransform="rotate(90, 0.5, 0.5)" id="uniqueDomId-1114">
                      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#AFAFAF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#F5F3F8" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                      <stop offset="69.804%" stop-color="#F9F9F9" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                   </linearGradient>

                   <filter id="uniqueDomId-1115" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-15.75" y="-15.75" width="303.5" height="76.5">
                      <feFlood result="floodOut" flood-color="#CCC1DA" flood-opacity="0.29"></feFlood>
                      <feGaussianBlur result="gaussOut" in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2.450000047683716,2.450000047683716">
                      </feGaussianBlur>
                      <feComposite in="floodOut" in2="gaussOut" operator="in"></feComposite>
                   </filter>

                </defs>

                <use transform="translate(-2.72, -0.45) scale(1.0199999809265137, 1.0199999809265137) translate(0, 0)" xlink:href="#uniqueDomId-1116" filter="url(#uniqueDomId-1115)" data-angle="0" data-distance="0" data-height="45" data-scale="1.02" data-adornment-type="drop-shadow" data-width="272" data-transform="[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;translate&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[-2.72,-0.45]},{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;scale&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[1.0199999809265137,1.0199999809265137]}]"></use>

                <g id="uniqueDomId-1116">
                   <g id="uniqueDomId-1117">
                      <path d="M0,0L272,0 272,45 0,45z" id="uniqueDomId-1118" fill="url(#uniqueDomId-1114)"></path>
                   </g>
                   
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <!-- End Box -->

    </div>

    <!-- background rectangle -->
    <div class="background-rectangle" style="min-width: 0; min-height: 0; height: 16.81vh; width: 15.54vw;">
        <svg height="16.81vh" width="15.54vw" viewBox="0 0 272 186" data-commandset-id="35" preserveAspectRatio="none">
            <g >
                <path d="M259.147003,1E-06C266.245483,-1.2E-05 271.999939,5.754436 271.999969,12.852937 271.999969,12.85294 271.999969,12.852942 271.999969,12.852945L271.999969,12.852945L271.999969,171.147034C271.999969,178.245529 266.245514,183.999985 259.147034,183.999985L259.147034,183.999985L12.852946,183.999985C5.754463,183.999985 3E-06,178.245529 0,171.147049L0,171.147049L0,12.85295C-5E-06,5.754468 5.754446,7E-06 12.852927,-1E-06z" id="uniqueDomId-1466" fill="#E6E0EC" fill-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="1" stroke="#CCC1DA" stroke-opacity="0.14" stroke-linecap="flat" stroke-linejoin="round" data-stroke-sharpened="true" transform="translate(0.5, 0.5)"></path>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>

    </div>

    <!-- box-container end -->


</div> <!-- main container end-->


<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

We should see the whole boxes inside the dashed container not overflowing it.

What I'm missing and how to fix this?!

Please help I'm really confused why this doesn't work?! I did whetever I did for the width to work but height does something totaly different and unexpected :(

Comment: It's rather unclear what you want. Why do you use a fixed `height` setting instead of `height: auto`? (which would expand to the height of all its contents)

Comment: I just want to fit the elements inside `main-container` with whatever width and height the `main-container` has... for instance I want the `main-container` with the height of `20px` ...

Comment: you you want the contents to shrink to fit into the container?

Comment: That's the word I was looking for... Shrinking the content to fit in the container...

Comment: But as long as you are giving those elements a fixed height, that's impossible

Comment: In the second snippet, I gave the container a fixed width and it works fine for the width

Comment: And that's the wired part because I set the same settings for the height and width! for width, everything works fine for height not...

Comment: Your height settings use the `vh` unit. If those result in a sum that's larger than your (fixed/px) container height, you have to change one of these two settings if you want to avoid that the contents go out of the container. One way would be to use percentage settings for the height of items - those refer to the (defined) parent height.

Comment: And why the same setting works fine for width?

Comment: Also, there is not any change in the height of elements with any height of the container

Comment: regarding width: Because you have a setting `max-width: 100%` for `.box` which limits the width to the width of the container. Concerning height, there are two elements which have `max-height: 100%`, so that adds up to 200% for two elements...

Comment: You say it's impossible to fit a box inside a fixed height container... What should I do?

Comment: If you know that there will be two elements in there, you can use `max-height: 50%` to fit two in there, but if the number of child elements is variable/dynamic, you'd need some javascript to apply calculated height settings when the page is loaded.

Comment: Another solution could be to use `display: flex` on the parent and allow the children to shrink. But if this makes sense, also depends on the contents of those elements - it wouldn't make sense to apply it to a text container for example.

Comment: I don't understand your last solution may I ask you to provide an answer, please?